# Proving the excess of two split triangles is the same as the original

Tags: triangles, noneuclidean-geometry

The excess of a triangle is the number of degrees over $180$ a triangle has in spherical geometry.

Given spherical $\triangle ABC$ that is split into two triangles by an arc from the vertex going to the opposite side. Show that the excess of $\triangle ABC=$ the excess of $\triangle ABD$+ the excess of $\triangle BDC$.

I drew this picture: [image]

Essentially it seems that $\angle ABC=\angle ABD+\angle DB$C.

I therefore need the excess defined by the two "bottom angles" of each smaller triangle to be the same as the excess defined by $\angle BAC$ and $\angle BCD$.
Because each of the smaller triangles only has one angle that is different than those of the larger triangle, the excess from the two angles formed by $d$ needs to be half of what is contributed by $\angle BAD$ and $\angle BCD$. Is this true?

Comment: But in your picture it looks more like you should be adding the two "smaller" angles that have B as middle vertex --- can't see why you consider angle BDA or angle BDC.

Comment: If the sphere radius is chosen appropriately (don't remember scale) and angles are in radians, then the excess of a triangle is same as its area. [I don't have a reference but I did go through why at some point while studying spherical geometry.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be the interior angles of the larger triangle at $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively,
- $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ be the angles of the smaller triangles at $B$, and
- $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$ be the angles of the smaller triangles at $D$.

Then $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = \beta$ and $\delta_1 + \delta_2 = 180$ degrees. Therefore the sum  of excesses of the smaller triangles is
$$
 (\alpha + \beta_1 + \delta_1 - 180) + (\gamma+\delta_2 + \beta_2 - 180) 
 = \alpha + \beta + \gamma - 180
$$
and therefore equal to the excess of the larger triangle.

Comment: Is it a given that $\delta_1 + \delta_2 = 180$?

Comment: @Burt: They add up to the angle between the arcs from $D$ to $A$ and $C$, respectively, and that is $180$ degrees.

Comment: That seems intuitive, but can you explain how you know that it is 180 degrees?

Comment: @Burt: The [spherical angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_angle) is measured by the angle between the planes containing the arcs. The arcs $DA$ and $DC$ are on the same plane through the center of the sphere, only in opposite direction.

Comment: @Burt: The angle between two arcs is also equal to the angle between their projections onto a tangent plane at the point where they meet. The projection of $ADC$ onto the tangent plane at $D$ is a line segment $A'DC'$, and the angle between $DA'$ and $DC'$ is $180$ degrees.